# Can we use C macro-function to define variables;

Tags: macros

```
#define def_1(var) { \
   int s[var]; \
}

int main(){

    def_1(2);

    s[0]=1; s[1]=3;
    printf("s[0]=%d\t s[1]=%d\n", s[0], s[1]);

    return;
}
```

Above code has compilation error indicating that s is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is because you have curly braces around the definition of s. Remove the curly braces from your macro and it should compile.

i.e. change:

```
#define def_1(var) { \
   int s[var]; \
}
```

to

```
#define def_1(var)   int s[var];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and yes it does. Your `#define` adds your variable to a one line block, I think you want to change this

```
#define def_1(var) { \ int s[var]; \ }
```

to something like this

```
#define def_1(var) int s[var];
```